# Finding a user profile match in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3, querying

I have a user who speaks **native language** lets say **English** and wants to **learn French**.

How can I find a list of match where users **native is French** and wants to **learn English**.
Its a language exchange program so I would like to list users with the match.

I have Users, Language_User and Language table. in Language_User table I have an extra field called type(learn or native).

## Users

id

name

...

## Language_User

id

user_id

language_id

type('learn','native')

## Language

id

language

## Queries

First I am getting all the users that does not have a role as 'Admin' or is not him/herself.

```
$other_users = User::with('languages')->with('departments')->with('hobbies')->with('universities')->with('years')->where([['id', '<>', Auth::user()->id],['role', '<>', 2]])->get();
```

Then, I am getting loggedin users $learn language and $native language to compare with other users

```
$learn = Auth::user()->languages()->wherePivot('type', 'learn')->select('language_id')->first();

$native = Auth::user()->languages()->wherePivot('type', 'native')->select('language_id')->first();
```

## In View

gives loggedin user language to learn

```
{{$learn->language_id}}
```

gives loggedin user native language

```
{{$native->language_id}}
```

View Code

```
@foreach($other_users as $user)

    @foreach($user->languages as $lang)

        @if($lang['pivot']['type'] ==='native' AND $lang['pivot']['language_id'] ===$learn['language_id'])

            <tr>
                <td>{{$user->firstname}} </td>
                <td>{{$user->lastname}} </td>
                <td>{{$user->email}} </td>
                <td>{{$user->photo}} </td>
                <td>{{$user->bio}} </td>
                <td>{{$user['universities']->university}} </td>
                <td>{{$user['departments']->department}} </td>
                <td>{{$user['years']->year}} </td>

                <td>
                    @foreach($user->languages as $lang)
                        @if($lang['pivot']['type'] === 'native')
                            {{$lang["language"]}}
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                </td>

                <td>
                    @foreach($user->languages as $lang)
                        @if($lang['pivot']['type'] === 'learn')
                            {{$lang["language"]}}
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                </td>

                <td>
                    @foreach($user->hobbies as $hobby)
                        {{$hobby->hobby}} <br>
                    @endforeach
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

I am unable to put **two** if conditions one for checking native language and one for checking learn language. if I do like this:

```
@if($lang['pivot']['type'] ==='native' AND $lang['pivot']['language_id'] ===$learn['language_id'])
@if($lang['pivot']['type'] ==='learn' AND $lang['pivot']['language_id'] ===$native['language_id'])
```

I get no rows, whereas user do exist with a match.

I think because I have two pivot type learn and native in an array. how to compare both learn and native? below shown languages format. its many to many relation

```
"languages":[  
   {  
      "id":3,
      "language":"Spanish",
      "pivot":{  
         "user_id":2,
         "language_id":3,
         "type":"native"
      }
   },
   {  
      "id":4,
      "language":"Greek",
      "pivot":{  
         "user_id":2,
         "language_id":4,
         "type":"learn"
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: Just to double check, you just want to show a list of other users that are want to learn `Auth::user()`'s native language **and** their native language is one that the `Auth::user()` want's to learn?

Comment: @RossWilson Yes. correct

Comment: Also, am I correct in assuming that a user can want to learn more than one language?

Comment: @RossWilson No, number of languages one can learn or teach has to be exactly one. But when finding users for a match. There could be list of users because if I want to learn french and teach english there could be 100s of profile who wants vice-versa of my preferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of loop through all the users in the database you could just constrain your query:

```
$native = Auth::user()->languages()->wherePivot('type', 'native')->first();

$learn = Auth::user()->languages()->wherePivot('type', 'learn')->first();

$other_users = User::with('departments', 'hobbies', 'universities', 'years', 'languages')
    ->where('id', '<>', Auth::user()->id)
    ->where('role', '<>', 2)
    ->whereHas('languages', function ($query) use ($learn) {
        $query->where('type', 'native')->where('id', $learn->id);
    })
    ->whereHas('languages', function ($query) use ($native) {
        $query->where('type', 'learn')->where('id', $native->id);
    })
    ->get();
```

Also, just an FYI, `$lang['pivot']['type']` can also be written as:

```
$lang->pivot->type;
```

Your blade section could then look something like:

```
@foreach($other_users as $user)

    <tr>
        <td>{{ $user->firstname }} </td>
        <td>{{ $user->lastname }} </td>
        <td>{{ $user->email }} </td>
        <td>{{ $user->photo }} </td>
        <td>{{ $user->bio }} </td>
        <td>{{ $user->universities->university }} </td>
        <td>{{ $user->departments->department }} </td>
        <td>{{ $user->years->year }} </td>
        <td>
            {{ $user->languages->where('pivot.type', 'learn')->first()->language }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ $user->languages->where('pivot.type', 'native')->first()->language }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {!! $user->hobbies->pluck('hobby')->implode('<br>') !!}
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for solution. I have one question, how to rewrite this much efficient way, you are right no need to loop but if i do $users->languages->pivot->type === 'native' I get error that languages unknown. So instead I do : \@foreach($user->languages as $lang)
      \@if($lang->pivot->type ==='native')
      {{$lang->language}}
      \@endif  
      \@endforeach

Comment: @MurlidharFichadia I've added an example of how you could rewrite your blade foreach.